# Android: Width of a grid of buttons screen does not change with different screen resolutions

Tags: java, android

My app makes a grid of 16x16 buttons. These are all set to 30dp in width and height. That makes 480x480dp. When testing on a 800x480 screen the app displays fine. But when I set my emulator to 400x240, the app is really ugly and the grid of buttons gets wider than the screen.

To solve this problem, I set the width and height of buttons to a variable named "knopAfmeting". That variable looks like is set with this piece of code:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int schermBreedte = display.getWidth();
    int knopAfmeting = schermBreedte/16;
```

And then the buttons are set like this:

```
    Button button = new Button (this);
    button.setHeight(knopAfmeting);
    button.setWidth(knopAfmeting);
```

But when testing in a 400x240px screen, the app still displays the grid of buttons wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ... 
you don't need to set heigh/width for buttons, they will be set relatively..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
        <Button  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

========= 2nd suggestion ========

I am sorry, I understood your question in wrong way .. anyway I checked your code ..your mistake that you always calculate knopAfmeting based on width, that is correct if height is equal or greater than width .. but when height is less so you need to calculate knopAfmeting based on height .. in other words, get the smaller dimension.

so

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int schermBreedte =0;
if(display.getWidth()>display.getHeight())
    schermBreedte=display.getHeight()
else
    schermBreedte=display.getWidth();
int knopAfmeting = schermBreedte/16;
```

just you will get some space one right side .. you can center them all to make it nicer..

good luck ...

Comment: I cannot do anything in the .xml, because the field is generated with a loop of code in OnCreate().

Comment: why you don't  get the screen dimensions in pixel and divided them by 4 for height and width .. so you will get correct value.. and recalculate that when change orientation with onconfigurationchange().

Comment: Why should I divide them by 4?

Comment: Ok, I implemented the code and run it with debugger and a screen which was 400x240. When stepping trough the code, knopAfmeting indeed gets 15. Which is 240/16. But the buttons still become big :(

Comment: try to check the width of button in runtime .. this will give you a clue to figure out where is the problem .. may be there is a padding in grid .. may you show us how you implement the grid and buttons in code ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7115/discussion-between-mavix-and-mohammed)